# How to get all of the entries in a yaml file?

Tags: java, yaml

I am a bit clueless with how to get all of the entries in my stats yaml file here is what it looks like

```
PLAYERUUID:
  kills: 7
  deaths: 5
  points: 0
  wins: 0
  losses: 1
PLAYERUUID2:
  kills: 14
  deaths: 10
  points: 1
  wins: 1
  losses: 4
```

etc.
How would I get all both playerUUID and playerUUID2 so I could use it in a for loop? Would I need to add an external manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this depends on what your ultimate goal is, but if you just want to loop through all the keys you can use the [getKeys()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/configuration/ConfigurationSection.html#getKeys(boolean)) method:

```
yml.getKeys(true) //With yml being an instance of your configuration file
```

This will create a `Set<String>` of all the keys in the config, which you can  iterate through. The `true` parameter specifies that you want to loop through the subkeys as well. If you only want to iterate through the primary keys, set it to `false`.

To then retrieve the values of the keys, you can do something like this:

```
for (String key : yml.getKeys(true)) {
    int value = yml.getInt(key); //Assumes all the values in your config are integers
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```